# How to get to the Windows 8 Lock Screen on Microsoft Surface?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface

I just got my Microsoft Surface Tablet. So far it rocks, but I would like to be able to get to the main screen that shows date/time and background image (or, the "Lock Screen"). Thus far I have only been able to get there by hitting the power button twice. Is there a way to get there without hitting the power button?

Comment: Currently there are two excellent answers. How does one go about deciding the answer to accept?

Comment: Whichever you prefer! Generally, if multiple answers solve my problem, I choose whichever I think will be most useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This screen is called the "Lock Screen". It is shown when your computer is locked.

To lock your computer, you can:

1. Go to the start screen, click your name in the top-right corner, and choose "Lock". [image]
2. Or, press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

You can customize your lock screen through the "Personalize" settings page.

First activate the "Settings" Charm and choose "Change PC Settings":

[image]

Then select the "Personalize" page:

[image]

Comment: What if I don't have the keyboard attached and want to use the touch screen?

Comment: @GaTechThomas: See my edit.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I commented on the other answer in my question about using the touch screen.

Comment: @GaTechThomas: Nope you were right, you commented right before I added non-keyboard methods to my answer, when this was the only answer :)

Comment: @Matthew Like how both our Start screen screenshots feature Solitaire Collection ;)

Comment: @GrahamWager: Gotta keep those Free Cell/Spider skills up-to-date :)

Answer (score 9):

What is called the Lock Screen is available using the profile icon in the top right corner of the Start screen. Simply click it and click "Lock":

[image]

Alternatively, if you have a keyboard attached, <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will end in the same result.