# How to lock the computer?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the new shortcuts for Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/466789/what-are-the-new-shortcuts-for-windows-8)
>   [How to get to the Windows 8 Lock Screen on Microsoft Surface?](https://superuser.com/questions/493389/how-to-get-to-the-windows-8-lock-screen-on-microsoft-surface)

Without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> how can I lock my computer?

I only see Sleep, Shutdown and Restart in the Power charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also click your user name in the Start screen and select Lock.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> keyboard shortcut to lock your computer.